# how to wait for if/then/else to finish before continuing vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have code which renames and copies a selection of files recursively through folders into an output folder, depending on a few factors. I'm trying to add a progress bar as it is not clear when the process is finished, but the progressbar.maximum is not always the same. I'd like to set it to the number of files in the output folder, but the next task has already started to process those files, converting and copying/deleting, before the original task has completed. This means that I'd like the first task to complete entirely before the second task starts to process all the files in the folder. As far as I can make out, I think I need threading.tasks, but for the life of me I can't seem to get it to work, and I think it may be because of the recursive function within the sub.

So simple version... how do I prevent one if/then loop starting until the previous one has finished?

```
Private Sub finalise(ByVal folder As DirectoryInfo)
    Dim task1 As New Threading.Tasks.Task(Sub()

    Dim files = folder.GetFiles

         For Each doc In files
             Dim testvar = doc.FullName
             Dim pos1 = InStr(doc.FullName, "SAT\") - 1 'position in string marks beginning of project name
             Dim pos2 = doc.FullName.LastIndexOf("\") ' position in string marks last subfolder
             Dim NoofChars As Integer = pos2 - pos1 'number of chars to use from full string
             Dim filenameappend = doc.FullName.Substring(pos1, NoofChars) 'select the appropriate chars
             Dim append As String = filenameappend.Replace("\", " ") 'replace all teh \ with spaces
             Dim exten As String = Path.GetExtension(doc.FullName)
             Dim procfilepdf = Nothing
             Try
                 If exten = ".tmp" Then
                 Else

                     If exten = ".pdf" Then

                         doc.CopyTo(projDirectory & "\processfolder\" & append & " " & doc.Name)
                         'if you are looking at a pdf, copy it to process

                     Else 'if its not a pdf however...
                         procfilepdf = Path.ChangeExtension(doc.FullName, "pdf") 'change the variable extension to pdf ( not the file)
                         If File.Exists(procfilepdf) Then 'it must have already been copied

                         Else
                             doc.CopyTo(projDirectory & "\processfolder\" & append & " " & doc.Name)

                             'ie its not a PDF and there is no PDF version of that file
                             'copy the original to the process folder and prefix the filename with the filestructure of its parent project

                         End If
                     End If
                 End If


             Catch e As System.IO.IOException
                 MsgBox("some of these files already exist, has this already been done?")
             End Try


         Next


         For Each subfolder In folder.GetDirectories
             finalise(subfolder) 'recursive through all folders
         Next



     End Sub)
    ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    task1.Start()
    task1.Wait()
    Dim fileNo As Integer
    Dim procFiles = processfolder.GetFiles
    fileNo = procFiles.Count
    Label2.Text = fileNo
    Dim prog As Integer = fileNo
    Dim procexten As String
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oXLS As Excel.Workbook
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 1
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = fileNo
    ProgressBar1.Step = 1
    ProgressBar1.Value = 1


    For Each file In processfolder.GetFiles
        Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(file.Name)
        If ext = ".pdf" Then
        ElseIf ext = ".doc" Then
            Dim filepdf = Path.ChangeExtension(file.FullName, "pdf")
            oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            oWord.Visible = False
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(file.FullName)
            oDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(filepdf, Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF)
            oDoc.Close(False)
            oWord.Quit()
            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
            prog = prog - 1


        ElseIf ext = ".docx" Then
            Dim filepdf = Path.ChangeExtension(file.FullName, "pdf")
            oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            oWord.Visible = False
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(file.FullName)
            oDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(filepdf, Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF)
            oDoc.Close(False)
            oWord.Quit()
            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
            prog = prog - 1

        ElseIf ext = ".xls" Then
            Dim filepdf = Path.ChangeExtension(file.FullName, "pdf")
            oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oExcel.Visible = False
            oXLS = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(file.FullName)
            oXLS.Worksheets("Report").ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, filepdf)
            oXLS.Close(False)
            oExcel.Quit()
            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
            prog = prog - 1
        ElseIf ext = ".xlsm" Then
            Dim filepdf = Path.ChangeExtension(file.FullName, "pdf")
            oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oExcel.Visible = False
            oXLS = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(file.FullName)
            oXLS.Worksheets("Report").ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, filepdf)
            oXLS.Close(False)
            oExcel.Quit()
            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
            prog = prog - 1
        ElseIf ext = ".xlsb" Then
            Dim filepdf = Path.ChangeExtension(file.FullName, "pdf")
            oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oExcel.Visible = False
            oXLS = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(file.FullName)
            oXLS.Worksheets("Report").ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, filepdf)
            oXLS.Close(False)
            oExcel.Quit()
            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
            prog = prog - 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each procTest In procFiles
        Dim procfilepdf
        procexten = Path.GetExtension(procTest.FullName)
        If procexten = ".pdf" Then 'if you are looking at a pdf, do nothing
        Else 'if its not a pdf however...
            procfilepdf = Path.ChangeExtension(procTest.FullName, "pdf") 'change the variable extension to pdf ( not the file)
            If File.Exists(procfilepdf) Then 'check if there is a pdf version
                File.Delete(procTest.FullName) 'and if there is, delete the original.
            Else
                MsgBox("the file" & procTest.Name & "hasn't been converted to pdf automagically, you'll have to do it manuelly", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
            End If
        End If

    Next

    Dim Command As String = "/C pdftk " & processfolder.FullName & "\*.pdf cat output " & Final.FullName & "\" & cmbProjPicker.SelectedItem & ".pdf"
    Process.Start("cmd.exe", Command)

End Sub
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? It might be easier to use async await pattern than managing threads yourself.

Comment: .net framework 4.5.2

Comment: Not relevant to question, but instead of using all the `elseif`'s for `ext =` try  using a  Select Case statement, would make it a bit simpler for you. `Select Case ext` then you only need to write `Case ".xls"`. [Select Case example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/select-vbnet) would make it more simpler for you. Just thought i mention as you said you are learning as you are going along

Comment: Ah ok, I'll look into that! thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Nikhil could you suggest how async and await could work in this code?

Comment: Not a big VB.NET expert here but give me a couple of days if you can. WIll have a shot at it. Mind if I do something like this in C# and come back to you with that?